# Distinct inside String_Agg

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, string-aggregation

I am making a school assignment, though I am finished with it since I can't use distinct inside a `String_Agg`. But I get the 'SNS' more than once, so I was thinking if there is a way to distinct it so I only got it once.

I tried `distinct`, but found out it didn't work with `string_agg`, right now I am trying with a subquery, but I don't know how to do it.

```
select FAG$.FagID, FagNavn, STRING_AGG(Lektion$.LaererID, ',') 'Lærer'
from Fag$
join Lektion$
on Fag$.FagID= Lektion$.FagID
group by Fag$.FagID, FagNavn, LaererID
```

I expect the output to be:

```
"NET = KBEN, SNS"
```

example, instead of

```
"NET = KBEN"
"NET = SNS, SNS, SNS"
```

i get duplicates, so i want to get rid of the duplicates, if it is possible? :)

Comment: Remove LaererID from GROUP BY clause. (You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.)

Comment: Fantastic Jarlh! it worked, now i just need to narrow it down, since "SNS" has 15 lections in ""NET" it wil show "NET = SNS,KBEN,SNS,SNS,SNS" i hope you got my point! but your solution helped me along the way! :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff i added it now, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GROUP BY` should have the *unaggregated* columns in the `SELECT`.  `STRING_AGG()` is an aggregation function.  So you probably want:

```
select f.FagID, FagNavn, STRING_AGG(l.LaererID, ',') as Lærer
from Fag$ f join
     Lektion$ l
     on f.FagID = l.FagID
group by f.FagID, FagNavn;
```

If you still duplicates (which seems unlikely with an `id`, then you need to use a subquery of some sort to remove the duplicates.

Comment: So if i read this correctly (i am quite new at SQL) i need to do STRING_AGG(DISTINCT) instead of STRING_AGG(l.LaererID, ',') ? :)

Comment: @Tim . . . `LaererID` should not be duplicated, so you probably don't need `STRING_AGG(DISTINCT l.LaererID, ',')`.

Comment: when i run it, i get the output like this:

"NET = SNS,KBEN,SNS,SNS" and i can't get rid of those extra "SNS"

Comment: and i don't think u can run a distinct inside a string_agg, can u?

Comment: @Tim . . . That depends on the database, which was not tagged when I answered.

Answer (score 0):

Remove LaererID from group by

```
select FAG$.FagID, FagNavn, STRING_AGG(Lektion$.LaererID, ',') 'Lærer'
from Fag$
join Lektion$
on Fag$.FagID= Lektion$.FagID
group by Fag$.FagID, FagNavn
```